# I'm having trouble troubleshooting my function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to make a function that calculates the area of a triangle given the sides. Sometimes it works, but other times it returns 0.0 when it shouldn't or gives an error. My code is:

```
def triangle3S(s1,s2,s3):
  s = float((s1 + s2 + s3) / 2)
  a = float(sqrt(s * (s-s1) * (s-s2) * (s-s3)))
  print('The area of this triangle is ' + str(a))

triangle3S(float(input('1st side: ')),float(input('2nd side: ')),float(input('3rd side: ')))
```

The error it sometimes returns is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    triangle3S(float(input('1st side: ')),float(input('2nd side: ')),float(input('3rd side: ')))
  File "main.py", line 20, in triangle3S
    a = float(sqrt(s * (s-s1) * (s-s2) * (s-s3)))
ValueError: math domain error
```

I have sqrt(x) imported and it seems to be working as it should most of the time. I'm wondering why my function is so unreliable and how I can fix it.

Comment: For what input does it not work?

Comment: You cannot do `math.sqrt` with negative numbers. You also have to ensure that the triangle is possible.

Comment: try `a = float(sqrt(abs(......)))`

Comment: while you can do `abs` to solve for it, you cannot create a triangle if s < s1 or s2 or s3. s has to be greater than s1, s2, and s3.

Comment: Your logic should check for `The sum of any two edges will need to be larger than the third`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to import sqrt from math, and it's working for me. What are your imports and inputs?

```
import math

def triangle3S(s1,s2,s3):
    s = float((s1 + s2 + s3) / 2)
    a = float(math.sqrt(s * (s-s1) * (s-s2) * (s-s3)))
    print('The area of this triangle is ' + str(a))

triangle3S(float(input('1st side: ')),float(input('2nd side: ')),float(input('3rd side: ')))
```

output:

```
1st side: 1
2nd side: 1
3rd side: 1
```

The area of this triangle is 0.4330127018922193

the numbers [13, 2, 4] can't be calculated as area [calc web](https://www.calculator.net/area-calculator.html?triedge1=13&triedge1unit=meters&triedge2=2&triedge2unit=meters&triedge3=4&triedge3unit=meters&calctype=triangle&x=0&y=0#triangle)

[image]

you can use try and except or if else:

```
def triangle3S(s1,s2,s3):
    try:
        s = float((s1 + s2 + s3) / 2)
        a = float(math.sqrt(s * (s-s1) * (s-s2) * (s-s3)))
        print('The area of this triangle is ' + str(a))
    except:
        print("can't be calculated")
```

output:

```
1st side: 13
2nd side: 2
3rd side: 4
can't be calculated
```

Comment: using 1 1 1, it gives me the same answer as you, but with other values it gives an error. 13, 2, and 4, for example, give me that error message.

Comment: I imported math instead of just the sqrt and sin function and used math.sqrt and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Please dont post images in your response. Post the code so it is easier for OP to try it out.

Comment: sure no problem,

Comment: How does this solve his problem with negative sqrt?

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense! I ran it again with two sides that add up exactly to the third and that explains when it would return 0.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar because if two sides couldn't add up to a third side, that would cause the square root to be negative since s is half the sum of all sides. Using abs would allow the program to function, but it would give the area of an impossible triangle which isn't what I am trying to do.